# how to search closed excel file

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to search a closed excel file for a match then pull references relative to that match into a string which will then go into the open word doc, then repeat until all matches are found. I'm completely stuck on simply opening the excel file to access it to search to start with though.

It generates an excel process in task manager but I'm not able to reference it and I would actually expect it to open the application. I might be going about this the wrong way entirely.

```
Sub stringPrompt2()
'Find match
'build output
'put into word doc
'repeat

  Dim sSearchString As String
  Dim sSearchDirectory As String
  Dim dlgFile As FileDialog
  Dim vSelectedItem As Variant
  Dim Loc As Excel.Range
  Dim sPath As String

  sSearchString = InputBox("String to search for", vbOKOnly, "Search String")

  Set vSelectedItem = Application.FileDialog(filedialogtype:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  With vSelectedItem
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
  End With

  sPath = vSelectedItem.SelectedItems.Item(1)

  Workbooks.Open sPath ' it isn't launching excel here.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a variable to hold the workbook reference and assign the result of the Workbooks.Open command to that variable so that you can work with it :

```
Dim myWorkbook As Workbook

Set myWorkbook = Workbooks.Open sPath

' Then do whatever you want with the Workbook object
MsgBox(myWorkbook.Name)
```